# Edit custom customer group attribute (column) in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

Bonjour !

I try to edit some custom customer group fields in my Magento 2.3 but I don't know how to start.

I already have added some columns and displayed it in admin back-office with a module.

view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_group_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_group_columns">
        <column name="siret">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">SIRET</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="code_client">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Code client</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="zipcode">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Code postal</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

But now I want on the update form to have the capability to modify this fields (siret, code_client, zipcode)

[Screenshot of the BO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43bOB.png)

For exemple, here I only have 2 fields but I want to add for example the zipcode in the form.

[Screenshot of the update form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyi21.png)

Thanks :)